Calculating the electronic potential energy for hydrogen system using plane waves: What causes the poor convergence?
Problem definition
I am studying how plane waves and fast Fourier transforms (FFT) can be used as a basis set in quantum chemical calculations. As a toy problem, I aim to calculate the electronic potential energy for the 1s atomic orbital in a H atom. The H atom is placed at the center of a cubic unit cell with an edge size of $a_{0}$. This system has an analytical solution ($E_{\text{pot}} = -1$ Ht), which allows for an easy comparison.
In the graph as seen below, I plot the potential energy (in Ht) as function of the number of sampling points per Cartesian direction, both used in the Fourier transform as well as in the real-space numerical integration. Furthermore, I perform this analysis for varying edge size ($a_{0}$) of the cubic unit cell.
Questions

Why does the energy converge to a less negative value when using smaller unit cells? My - perhaps naive - intuition would say that if I use a smaller unit cell, the electron density experiences more (favorable) attraction due to a larger charge density. I would thus expect that the result converges to a more negative number.
Why does a larger unit cell require significantly more plane waves to reach convergence with respect to the number of plane waves? I reasoned that for a larger unit cell, the plane waves have fewer oscillation, giving a worse sampling of the space, thus requiring more plane waves. Is that reasoning valid?
I understand that in typical plane-wave electronic structure calculations pseudo-potentials are being used. I am under the impression that for the H-atom, due to its relatively limited charge, one can still do without, but perhaps that is not the case. Can this be the reason for the relatively poor convergence?


Other remarks

For reproduction purposes, I have included a (condensed) derivation of the equations used in my approach as well as a copy of the Python script to reproduce the figure shown above.
Full disclosure: I also asked this question on P.SE. From the comments, I got the impression that the typical terms used in electronic structure modelling were unfamiliar to this community, leading to confusion. Attempts to rewrite those terms to more general ones did not resolve upon the confusion, leading the question to be closed.

Derivation of equations used in numerical procedure
Given the charge density corresponding to a single nuclear charge
$$
\rho_{\text{nucleus}}(\vec{r}) = \delta(\vec{r} - \vec{R}).
$$
with $\vec{R}$ being the position of the nucleus. I can represent this charge density as a plane wave expansion via
$$
\rho(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_{\vec{G}} \tilde{\rho}(\vec{G}) \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{R} \right).
$$
To obtain the real-space nuclear attraction potential, I solve Poisson's equation in reciprocal-space (removing the divergent term corresponding to $\vec{G} = \vec{0}$) and perform a backward Fourier transform, i.e.
$$
\nu(\vec{r}) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\frac{-4\pi}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_{\vec{G} \neq \vec{0}} \frac{\tilde{\rho}(\vec{G})}{|\vec{G}|^{2}} \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{R} \right) \right].
$$
Finally, I calculate the nuclear attraction by evaluating
$$
E_{\text{nuc}} = \int_{\Omega} d\vec{r} \; |\psi_{\text{1s}}(\vec{r})|^{2} \; \nu(\vec{r})
$$
Numerical implementation in Python
To reproduce the graph as shown in the problem definition, please find below the Python script that I am using. As a kind warning, I perform this analysis up to 512 sampling points per Cartesian direction, generating ~134 million plane waves which is associated with a substantial memory footprint. Depending on your hardware, please take this into consideration before running the script on your own machine.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc
import tqdm

def main():    
    nptss = np.logspace(3,9,7, base=2)      # number of sampling points per cartesian direction
    a0s = [10,20,50,100,200]                # edge sizes of cubic unit cell
    vnuc = np.zeros((len(a0s), len(nptss))) # data container
    for i,s in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(a0s)):
        v = []
        for j,npts in enumerate(nptss):
            vnuc[i,j] = calculate_nuclear_attraction(int(npts), s)
        
    # build graph
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=144)
    for i,s in enumerate(a0s):
        ax.plot(nptss, vnuc[i,:], 'o--', label=r'$a_{0} = %.1f$ a.u.' % s)
    ax.grid(linestyle='--')
    ax.set_xscale('symlog')
    ax.set_yscale('symlog')
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of sampling points per cartesian direction [-]')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$E_{\text{pot}}$ [Ht]')
    ax.legend(loc='lower right')        
    plt.tight_layout()

def calculate_nuclear_attraction(npts, sz):
    """
    Calculate the potential energy of a 1s atomic orbital
    """
    r, k, k2 = build_lattice_points(sz, npts)
    
    # generate wave function
    R = np.array([sz/2,sz/2,sz/2])
    rRv =  r - R
    Rr = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ijk', rRv, rRv))
    wf = 1.0 / np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(-Rr)
    
    # generate structure factor and nuclear attraction field
    sf = np.exp(-1j * k @ R) / np.sqrt(sz**3)
    ct = np.sqrt(sz**3) / npts**3
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        nupotg = -4.0 * np.pi / k2
        nupotg[0,0,0] = 0
    vnuc = sc.fft.ifftn(sf * nupotg) / ct
    
    dV = (sz/npts)**3 # real-space integration constant
    Enuc = np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk', wf, wf, vnuc).real * dV
    
    return Enuc

def build_lattice_points(sz, npts):
    """
    Build the lattice points, both in real-space as well as in reciprocal space.
    Also calculate the squared reciprocal space vector magnitudes
    """
    # determine grid points in real space
    c = np.linspace(0, sz, npts, endpoint=False)

    # construct real space sampling vectors
    z, y, x = np.meshgrid(c, c, c, indexing='ij')
    
    N = len(c)
    cvec = np.zeros((npts, npts, npts, 3))
    cvec[:,:,:,0] = x
    cvec[:,:,:,1] = y
    cvec[:,:,:,2] = z
    
    # calculate plane wave vector coefficients in one dimension
    k = np.fft.fftfreq(npts) * 2.0 * np.pi * (npts / sz)
    
    # construct plane wave vectors
    k3, k2, k1 = np.meshgrid(k, k, k, indexing='ij')
    
    N = len(k)
    kvec = np.zeros((N,N,N,3))
    kvec[:,:,:,0] = k1
    kvec[:,:,:,1] = k2
    kvec[:,:,:,2] = k3
    
    k2 = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ijk', kvec, kvec)
    
    return cvec, kvec, k2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


You are supposed to cross-post or migrate the original question from P.SE to here, not delete the P.SE question and repost it here without all the comments that had already been attached to the original question.

Thank you for that feedback. I have undeleted the question on P.SE. I see however no option for cross-posting or migration.

I don't have time to write an answer now, but the key numerical convergence criterion is the minimum wavelength of your plane-wave set (or, equivalently, the maximum wave-vector, from which we define the more common "plane-wave cut-off energy")

Let me start by first briefly answering your questions. In what follows thereafter, I will provide an example to explain the concepts better.
Brief answer to questions

Why does the energy converge to a less negative value when using
smaller unit cells? My - perhaps naive - intuition would say that if I
use a smaller unit cell, the electron density experiences more
(favorable) attraction due to a larger charge density. I would thus
expect that the result converges to a more negative number.

This is caused by the removal of $\vec{G}=\vec{0}$-term in the Fourier expansion. Your system is not charge-neutral. If you would also calculate the electron-electron repulsion on top of the attraction of the electron(s) by the nucleus, the $\vec{G}=\vec{0}$-term in that calculation would cancel out with the first one, giving much better convergence.

Why does a larger unit cell require significantly more plane waves to
reach convergence with respect to the number of plane waves? I
reasoned that for a larger unit cell, the plane waves have fewer
oscillation, giving a worse sampling of the space, thus requiring more
plane waves. Is that reasoning valid?

This questions was already correctly answered by Phil Hasnip in the comments. A bigger unit cell requires many more plane waves to reach a certain cut-off energy.

I understand that in typical plane-wave electronic structure
calculations pseudo-potentials are being used. I am under the
impression that for the H-atom, due to its relatively limited charge,
one can still do without, but perhaps that is not the case. Can this
be the reason for the relatively poor convergence?

For very light atoms, you could in principle do without.
Example
Consider the following normalized wave function, corresponding to a Gaussian
$$
\phi(\vec{r}) = \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \right)^{3/4} \exp \left(-|\vec{r}|^{2} \right).
$$
The electron-electron repulsion and the nuclear-attraction energy (by a nucleus with a charge of +1) for this Gaussian can be evaluated analytically (see e.g. the book of Szabo and Ostlund for a derivation) and correspond to
$$
E_{\text{e-e}} = \left<{\phi(\vec{r}_{1})\phi(\vec{r}_{2})\left|\frac{1}{r_{12}^{-1}}\right|\phi(\vec{r}_{1})\phi(\vec{r}_{2})}\right> = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}
$$
and
$$
E_{\text{nuc}} = \left<\phi(\vec{r})\left|\frac{1}{r}\right|\phi(\vec{r})\right> = -2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}},
$$
yielding a total energy of
$$
E_{\text{tot}} = \frac{2 \left( 1 - \sqrt{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}.
$$
Note that the complete system is neutral. The normalized Gaussian wave functions corresponds to a total charge of -1 and the nucleus has a charge of +1.
In the image below, the electron-electron repulsion and the nuclear-attraction energy and their sum are approximated by means of a plane-wave expansion using a procedure analogous to the one provided in your answer (i.e. via forward and backward Fourier transforms).
As can be seen from the graph, despite that the individual terms ($E_{\text{nuc}}$ and $E_{\text{e-e}}$) exhibit relatively poor convergence, their sum ($E_{\text{tot}}$) reproduces the exact answer with relatively few plane waves. For example, for $a_{0} = 10$ we observe that 16 sampling points per Cartesian direction (4096 plane waves), already reproduces the analytical result with sufficient accuracy.

Conclusively, the convergence does not have to be poor and pseudo-potentials are not necessarily required for the calculation of a H atom. In practice, i.e. in an actual electronic structure calculation, one would not calculate the individual terms but always use them in a sum. This would automatically result in the (beneficial) cancellation of the $\vec{G}=\vec{0}$-terms.
